# Why is a non-linear transformation a parameter?

Tags: correlation, data-transformation

This in reference to my answer at [What model should I use to prove statistical significance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517884/what-model-should-i-use-to-prove-statistical-significance/517892#517892).

I test the correlation between `x` and `log10(y)`, specifically, in R:

```r
Satisfaction = c(55, 34, 24, 12, 17, 10, 14)
Tenure = c(0.5, 2, 4.5, 8, 13, 17.5, 20)

cor.test(Satisfaction, log10(Tenure))
```

Whuber in comments points out that the model has 3 parameters: In addition to the "familiar" slope and intercept, the third is the choice of non-linear transformation.

I'm puzzled by the non-linear transformation being counted as a parameter and I would appreciate some explanation.

I understand that choosing a transformation, especially after having seen the data, should be penalized as a form of multiple hypothesis testing. But I don't see it as a parameter and in fact I'm not estimating it, I'm just imposing it. I'm also puzzled because I have never seen in literature transformations being considered a parameter. Usually, you transform to make the data better behaved or more interpretable, but I haven't seen this done at a cost.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand or fully appreciate the distinction you're making between "estimating" and "imposing." It seems to be a psychological distinction rather than a statistical one.  What is "imposition" if not a poorly-described *ad hoc* estimate of a transformation? If you are experienced in making such transformations you might have implicitly selected one from a multiparameter family (such as a Box-Cox family with offset) and if you're not experienced, maybe you guessed from a small finite set of possibilities.  But isn't that a form of *estimation* in either case?

Comment: @whuber my choice of words may be inappropriate but that's what I mean. If I *estimate* use the data if I *impose* I know beforehand what the appropriate value should be. I guess I have in mind the difference between *offset* and *covariate* in the context of glm. As I say in my question (sentence *I understand that choosing...*), I also find the distinction blurred but I'm puzzled that such transformations are rarely (never?) treated as a parameter to be estimated and therefore suck up degrees of freedom.

Comment: If "impose" really means "know beforehand," then that uses no parameters.  I cannot reconcile that with the context, though, in which you were responding to a presentation of data and determined (1) that a re-expression of the values would be useful and (2) the specific re-expression should be a logarithm.  That doesn't seem to comport with your definition of "impose."

Comment: @whuber thanks for engaging in the discussion - I posted an answer with some further thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

I think I disagree that the transformation is a third parameter in `cor(x, log10(y))`.

I agree that choosing a transformation after having seen the data is a form of estimation and therefore should impact on the interpretation of the results (correlation coefficient and p-value in this case).

However, if I receive a new dataset as a replicate experiment, I wouldn't decide on a different transformation. I would choose the logarithmic transformation even before seeing the new data. This is in contrast with the slope and intercept that would have to be re-estimated on the new dataset.

Perhaps more importantly, even if I didn't log-transform I would still have considered in my mind various options and decided for the *identity* transformation (*i.e.* leave the data as it is). Effectively this is what I've done for the variable `Satisfaction`. Would that be a fourth parameter that I estimated from the data?

I guess this is what Andrew Gelman calls [Garden of Forking Paths](http://stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/ForkingPaths.pdf). As a very rough guideline when I see a p-value, including those from my own analyses, I mentally multiply it by, say, 10x to account for all the things that have been or couldn't have been done on the data before the results have been finalized.